# "to get at our leaks"

Tags: meaning

> The next English frigate we escaped with no more than a shot in our
>   quarter.  Then we was chased two days and a night by a French
>   privateer, firing between squalls, and the dirty little English
>   ten-gun brig which made him sheer off had the impudence to press
>   another five of our men. That's how we reached to the chops of the
>   Channel. Twelve good men pressed out of thirty-five; an eighteen-pound
>   shot-hole close beside our rudder ; our mainsail looking like
>   spectacles where the Frenchman had hit us--and the Channel crawling
>   with short-handed British cruisers. Put that in your pipe and smoke it
>   next time you grumble at the price of tobacco! 'Well, then, to top it
>   off, while we was trying **to get at our leaks**, a French lugger come
>   swooping at us out o' the dusk.

This is from "Rewards and Fairies" "A Priest in Spite of Himself" by Kipling.
http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/RewardsFaries/priest.html

What is the meaning of "to get at our leaks" ?

I am glad if some one kindly teach me.

Answer (score 2):

The English ship had been hit by a French cannon.  The crew was trying to stop the leaks, and while they were doing so a second French ship showed up.

Kipling is writing in the older, wordier style common in the nineteenth and early twentieth centuries (the piece was [published in 1910](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewards_and_Fairies)). He was also using idiomatic phrases he thought might have been used by sailors at the time.

Comment: @RicgF, Thank you so much for your answer! It so helpful for me.